# Rails3/Mongoid - save model to lowercase

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid

I'm using Rails 3.1 and Mongoid. What would be the proper way to enforce that a field of my model is saved to lowercase? I don't see this in the Mongoid documentation but I was wondering if there is a clean way I should know about. Thanks much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok so I read the documentation more thoroughly, which I should have done initially. And this works for me now.

in the model.rb:

```
...
before_create :drop_the_case

protected
def drop_the_case
  self.MYMODELFIELD = self.MYMODELFIELD.downcase
end
```

"drop_the_case" being my own arbitrary name for this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In your model you can use

```
def before_save
  self.your_model_field = your_model_field.downcase
end
```

or

```
def before_save
    self.your_model_field.downcase!
end
```

Take a look at http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/109091 This should work !!

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer with the `before_create` callback has some big issues, especially if you use certain constraints like `validates_uniqueness_of`. Use the `before_validation` callback instead when possible.

```
class Safe
    include Mongoid::Document
    field :foo, type: String

    validates_uniqueness_of :foo

    before_validation :drop_the_case

    protected
    def drop_the_case
        self.foo = self.foo.downcase
    end
end

class Dangerous
    include Mongoid::Document
    field :foo, type: String

    validates_uniqueness_of :foo

    before_create :drop_the_case

    protected
    def drop_the_case
        self.foo = self.foo.downcase
    end
end

dangerous = Dangerous.create!(name: 'BAR')
safe = Safe.create!(name: 'BAR')

dangerous.update(name: 'BAR') # dangerous.name => BAR
safe.update(name: 'BAR') # safe.name => bar

Dangerous.create!(name: 'BAR') # => true, unique constraint ignored
Safe.create!(name: 'BAR') # throws exception
```

Comment: You could also add case_sensitive: false to the uniqueness validation.  For example: 

  validates_uniqueness_of :foo, :case_sensitive => false